# Reverse Geocoding On A Pin

Tags: swift, maps

I can't figure out how to show the street address, city, etc as the subTitle on a pin using reverse geocoding- whenever a user adds a pin. This is my code so far. I assumed I had to write "annotation.subTitle = CLLocationCoordinate2D" in order to show it on the pin, but it doesn't seem to work. What do I do?
[image: Screenshot 1]

Comment: It's hard to know where you might be stuck here, what have you tried? What does the result you see tell you about what is happening? For starters you appear to have a `reverseGeocodeLocation` function which is never called.

Comment: @Jonah I'm new to coding, so I'm still sort of learning how to do things. How do I need to call it? I thought what I was doing was pretty much activating the subtitle to read on the pin the users street address.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there's some confusion about Swift syntax here so I'll try to address that and see if it leads to a solution to the problem you're trying to solve. Please forgive me if I'm explaining code you already understand.

*Reading the example code:*

For starers I see a function declaration:

```
func action(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) { ...
```

Here we have a function named `action` with one argument named `gestureRecognizer` which is a `UIGestureRecognizer`. I assume that somewhere not shown in the question a `UIGestureRecognizer` has been created which will call this function when it detects an appropriate gesture.

Within the `action` function we print "Gesture Recognized" to the console. I assume you'll see that if you run this app and perform the appropriate gesture on the appropriate view.

Next we obtain the gesture's location and store it in a local constant named `touchPoint`. If we look at the [UIGestureRecognizer class reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1624219-location) we see that `UIGestureRecognizer`'s `location` returns a `CGPoint` type which is "A point in the local coordinate system of view that identifies the location of the gesture.". Again so far so good, it looks like we're detecting a gesture and locating where in some view the gesture, probably a tap, occurred.

Now it get's somewhat confusing:

```
func reverseGeocodeLocation(_ location: CLLocation, completionHandler: @escaping CLGeocodeCompletionHandler)
```

declares a new nested function named `reverseGeocodeLocation`. This isn't automatically bad, you might want to create a nested function to define some reusable behavior (there's a discussion of nested function in the [Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID178)). However in this case this seems to be a copy of an existing method from [`CLGeocoder`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/clgeocoder/1423621-reversegeocodelocation) and I suspect that what you want to do is call that existing function, not define a new function of the same name with totally unrelated behavior.

We then have a block of code provided as the function body of this nested function. As shown this `reverseGeocodeLocation` nested function is never called so this code is never executed. It looks to me like this is meant to be a completion handler passed to `CLGeocoder`'s `reverseGeocodeLocation` which will then execute once a location has been reverse geocoded.

*Solving the problem (partially)*

In order to call `CLGeocoder`'s existing function we need to obtain an instance of `CLGeocoder`. This is an instance method we need a reference to some existing geocoder object on which we can call this function. We then need to build a valid set of arguments to pass to `reverseGeocodeLocation`.

Looking at the class reference `CLGeocoder` doesn't have any custom initializers, we don't need to supply it with any data in order to create an instance so we can just call `CLGeocoder()`

Looking at `reverseGeocodeLocation` we see a slightly complicated set of arguments:

```
func reverseGeocodeLocation(_ location: CLLocation, completionHandler: @escaping CLGeocodeCompletionHandler)
```

We have to pass `reverseGeocodeLocation` two arguments. `location` is a [`CLLocation`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocation), that's not too bad, we can build one of those from a pair of coordinates so I bet there's a way to convert the location of our `touchPoint`'s screen coordinates into a latitude and longitude.  `completionHandler` is a [`CLGeocodeCompletionHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/clgeocodecompletionhandler), that's a little more complicated, this is a [closure](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) which captures some behavior and provides two arguments of its own.

Let's try this out in an Xcode Playground before trying to add it to the app:

```
import CoreLocation
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true // We're using asynchronous behavior here so we need this to tell the Playground to keep running until our reverse geocoding finishes rather than stopping immediately when it reaches the end of our example code.
let location = CLLocation(latitude: 37.332112, longitude: -122.0329646) // Somewhere near Apple HQ should geocode successfully
let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemarks, error) in
    print(placemarks?.first?.name)
    PlaygroundPage.current.finishExecution() // Now that our async task has completed we can tell the playground that it is time to stop running.
}
```

*Almost there*

Now we've seen how to geocode a location so we can add that behavior to our app. We have to solve 2 problems to make that happen.

1. We need to not only create a `CLGeocoder` to perform the reverse geocoding but also store it until it finishes. If we just create a geocoder in our `action` function then function will finish and the geocoder could be destroyed before it has time to finish geocoding. One way to solve this would be to add the geocoder as a property of the view controller (or whatever class it is) which contains this `action` function so that the geocoder exists as long as the object using it.
2. We need to convert the view coordinates of our `touchPoint` into a `CLLocation`. If we're touching an `MKMapView` then its [`convert`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkmapview/1452503-convert) function might be exactly what we need.